# JSF Command Button on IE Dialog Modal window

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, iframe, modal-dialog, jsf-1.2

I am trying to export excel from a JSF button on IE11 Dialog Modal window.
We had added iframe (containing that button) with X-Frame-Options header with "SAMEORIGIN", and it was working fine. But It was failed in PCI compliance.

Now, I have removed the complete iframe, and just added that command button on JSF form. the request and excel file generation is working fine, but the export "Open"/"Save" option on IE is not responding.

Comment: And what help do ypu expect/hope to get from us. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Kukelje, I am knowing about stackoverflow..

Comment: My query is asking for a solution, which would resolve my issue along with PCI compliance.

Comment: Without PCI compliance, I had already told about the solution. But now is the need for PCI appiance